# Python Click: Having the group execute code AFTER a command

Tags: python, python-click

I have a `click.group()` defined, with about 10 commands in it. I understand how to use a group to run code before the code in the command, but I also want to run some code AFTER each command is run. Is that possible with click?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`@resultcallback`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/master/api/#click.MultiCommand.resultcallback) decorator

```
@click.group()
def cli():
    click.echo('Before command')


@cli.resultcallback()
def process_result(result, **kwargs):
    click.echo('After command')


@cli.command()
def command():
    click.echo('Command')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Output:

```
$ python cli.py command
Before command
Command
After command
```

Comment: Note that `resultcallback` has been renamed to `result_callback`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on `Click==7.0`. Have not tried resultcallback

```py
$ cat check.py 
import click

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    print("> Welcome!!")
    ctx.call_on_close(_on_close)

def _on_close():
    print("> Done!!")

@cli.command()
def hello():
    print("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 check.py hello
> Welcome!!
Hello
> Done!!
```

[Documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/?highlight=call_on_close#click.Context.call_on_close)