# Python click command exit flow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I have this python click CLI design (`wificli.py`). At the end of command execution, it prints only respective print messages.

For example, when executed command `python3.7 wificli.py png`, it prints only `png` and when executed command `python3.7 wificli.py terminal` it prints only `terminal`.

As I have shown, I am expecting that it would also print `End of start function` and `End of the main function` but it is not. The idea is that to do clean up of resources only at one place rather than at each exit point of the respective command.

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.option('--ssid', help='WiFi network name.')
@click.option('--security', type=click.Choice(['WEP', 'WPA', '']))
@click.option('--password', help='WiFi password.')
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, ssid: str, security: str = '', password: str = ''):
    ctx.obj['ssid'] = ssid
    ctx.obj['security'] = security
    ctx.obj['password'] = password


@main.command()
@click.pass_context
def terminal(ctx):
    print('terminal')

@main.command()
@click.option('--filename', help='full path to the png file')
@click.pass_context
def png(ctx, filename, scale: int = 10):
    print('png')

def start():
    main(obj={})
    print('End of start function')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
    print('End of main function')
```

When executed

Answer (score 1):

As you've not asked a specific question, I can only post what worked for me with the reasoning behind it, and if this is not what you are looking for, I apologize in advance.

```py
@main.resultcallback()
def process_result(result, **kwargs):
    print('End of start function')
    click.get_current_context().obj['callback']()

def start():
    main(obj={'callback': lambda: print('End of main function')})
```

So, the `resultcallback` seems to be the suggested way of handling the termination of the group, and the invoked command. In our case, it prints `End of start function`, because at that point, the start function has finished executing, so we are wrapping up before terminating `main`. Then, it retrieves the callback passed in via the context, and executes that.

I am not sure if this is the idiomatic way of doing it, but it seems to have the intended behaviour.

For the result callback, a similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164324/python-click-having-the-group-execute-code-after-a-command)

As to what exactly is causing this behaviour, and this is only a guess based on some quick experimentation with placing yield in the group or the command, I suspect some kind of thread/processor is spawned to handle the execution of the group and its command.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

click's [main()](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.BaseCommand.main) always raises a SystemExit. Quoting the documentation:

> This will always terminate the application after a call. If this is not wanted, SystemExit needs to be caught.

In your example, change `start()` to:

```
def start():
    try:
        main(obj={})
    except SystemExit as err:
        # re-raise unless main() finished without an error
        if err.code:
            raise
    print('End of start function')
```

Answer (score 0):

See the **click** [docs here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/exceptions/) also this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71267041/3426192)

```
# Main Runtime call at bottom of your code
start(standalone_mode=False)

# or e.g
main(standalone_mode=False)
```